# rails: nested form showing multiple input fields after saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I only want to show 1 input field so I can just populate my list. However, each saved data is an input field. How do I prevent this? I just want to show the list and 1 input field.

This is my controller:

```
def show
  @project.milestones.build
end

def new
  @project = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<%= nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :milestones do |milestone_fields| %>
    Milestone: <%= milestone_fields.text_field :item %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Rails 4. not sure if that matters

---

[image: showing input fields]

Comment: Can you post your controller actions,specially the `new`,`create` and the `method` which holds the `params`?

Comment: @Pavan hello, I've updated my OP to show new and create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to iterate through your milestones and print each one

```
<% @project.milestones.each do |m| %>
  <p><%= m.item %></p>
<% end %>
```

Then you need to add a text field to insert a new milestone:

```
<%= f.fields_for :milestones, @project.milestones.build do |milestone_fields|
  <%= milestone_fields.text_field :item %>
<% end %>
```

Also remove the code in show method in your controller.

The only difference with your code is that I'm telling to `fields_for` what array should use in this case `@project.milestones.build` should return a unique element and not all the collection

Comment: Success!! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list THEN build the new object in the view, that should work.

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <% @project.milestones.each do |m| %>
        <p><%= m.item %></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for @project.milestones.build do |ff| %>
        Milestone: <%= ff.text_field :item %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Isn't my code the same thing just minus the list? also, if I change :milestones to @project.milestones.build, it doesn't save into database

Comment: Generally, I'll stay away from nested forms and render 'milestones/form' whenever I'm doing something like this. Otherwise, you're right. Basically the same except you're telling it to build form_fields for every project milestone instead of a single, brand new instance.

Comment: yeah. but i wanted nested forms so I can associate a project id to the milestone. But I guess I can just create a hidden field, right?

Answer (score 0):

yeah passing build object to nested form works
similar to the above

```
<%= f.fields_for :milestones, @project.milestones.build do |milestone_fields|
<%= milestone_fields.text_field :item %>
```

this can be beneficial while adding multiple styles of  product to the cart using nested form